# vim autocompletes wrong path when executing external script in a different path

Tags: vim, bash

When I try to execute external script using `:! <script>`, vim gives wrong autocomplete path. For example, if I have PythonTidy.py in ~/Dropbox/Work/Scripts/, and I have it added to $PATH in my bash profile using `export PATH="$PATH:~/Dropbox/Work/Scripts"`. If in vim I do `:!PythonTidy.py % %`, it will do the job, and `:!~/Dropbox/Work/Scripts/PythonTidy.py % %` also works. But if I do `:!Pyth` and press the tab key, vim will autocomplete it to `:!k/Scripts/PythonTidy.py`, which is wrong path. I suspect this behavior comes from the relative path. Anyone has ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing:

`export PATH="~/Dropbox/Work/Scripts:$PATH"`

which will add it as the first place to look for the script.

Then you'll see if the "k/Scripts/PythonTidy.py" is in the PATH prior, and thus found first by vim.

Comment: Vim still gives "k/Scripts/PythonTidy.py"